# Selenium use local server as RemoteWebdriver

Tags: selenium

I encountered a problem about Selenium.
I created a Selenium test by `RemoteWebdriver` class so the test can run in a remote machine which runs selenium-standalone-server (v3.4).

And I ran the standalone server in local and then change the url for the `RemoteWebdriver` to localhost, the connection created but I got the exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

I did specify the driver in my code as following:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", path_to_the_driver);
```

The driver path I specified in the server is existed. I tried every method I can find and it still doesn't work. Although I could just use `FirefoxDriver`, I still want to know why the problem occurred.

I'd appreciate any idea about this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify this not in your code but when you are launching selenium server jar

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/drivers/geckodriver-v0.18.0 -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.1.jar -port 4444
```

**Edit-1**

The reason is that when you Specify driver in your local code, that is used to launch browser locally. But in your case you are asking a Selenium Hub/Grid to launch a Browser. The server needs to know where the driver is located.

In your case your local Java process knows about the location but not the server Java process. That is why you need to use it with the server launch

Comment: Thanks @Tarun, it works! But now I feel confused why I can't specify the driver in my code ? Could you explain more? Thanks!

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot!